# Java Scanning Class for Annotation using Google Reflections

Tags: java, annotations, reflections

I am trying to scan the Fields inside the class for my custom Annotation using google reflections. I don't know why but the result is always an empty set.

**Test Class**

```
public class AnnotationParser {

    public void parse() {
        String packagename = "com.security.rest.client";

        final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(packagename);

        Set<Field> subTypes = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(Wire.class);

        for (Field field : subTypes) {
            System.out.println("Class : " + field.getName());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AnnotationParser().parse();
    }

}
```

**Annotated Class**

```
public class AuthenticationClient {

    @Wire
    public KerberosAPI kerberosAPI;
    @Wire
    public KerberosSessionManager kerberosSessionManager;
}
```

**Custom Annotation**

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Wire {

}
```

Please let me know if anyother information is required.

Answer (score 8):

Field annotations are not scanned by default.
You should add FieldAnnotationScanner to the list of scanners, something like:

```
new Reflections("com.security.rest.client", new FieldAnnotationsScanner())
```