# Implementing Dependency Injection using Custom Annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am working on a core java framework. I don't want to create instances directly inside the class which is why I want to use dependency injection.

I am thinking of declaring my custom annotations on the fields to be instantiated. And having a call back function which would create an instance and inject it into the field.

I had tried to create a custom annotation. But looks like there's no direct way to get a callback on the declared annotation. So, I was trying to scan the classes for that. But I ended up with this problem
[Java Scanning Class for Annotation using Google Reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780062/java-scanning-class-for-annotation-using-google-reflections)

Please let me know if this is the right way of achieving this.

Comment: So who will process the annotations and create and inject objects? It might help if you elaborate, using code examples.

Comment: I was wondering if I can have callback methods which would create and inject on the annotated fields

Comment: I don't have much experience with custom annotations but I don't think you can get callback methods for annotations. One option is to use `AspectJ`, so you can annotate these classes and do the magic in an aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is tagged 'Spring', you can use Spring Framework's bean annotations (@Component / @Service / @Repository / ...), classpath scanning and @Autowired.

For example:

Setup classpath scanning on your spring config xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.myapp" />
```

Create your bean to be scanned. Spring container will automatically create a singleton instance of this bean using default constructor:

```
@Repository
public class FooDAO {
  ...
}
```

Inject reference to above DAO instance using DI + autowiring

```
@Service
public class FooService {

  @Autowired private FooDAO fooDAO;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create a framework which would eventually be packaged as jar and eventually be used in other project. So, if I try to install spring dependency in my framework wouldn't exporting it in to a jar file cause problems?

Comment: Not if you used dependency management tool like Maven. You can declare what dependencies your project requires, and the pulling project will transitively pull all these dependencies

Comment: I gave it a shot by creating a spring project and importing it in a non maven project (one of my project requirements). And it seems to be working. Looks like the jar is self contained with all the dependencies. But when I checked the jar size, it is just a few kb!
Is there a reasonable explanation for this?